# easeljs - Container mouseEnabled not working

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm having a problem getting container when calling `getObjectsUnderPoint`.
According to the documentation of the `easeljs`, when `mouseEnabled` property set to `true` on container, on calling `getObjectsUnderPoint` it should return the container objects not its children.

In the sample code, I've two containers and each container has two children (shape and image). Its drag and drop sample. On mouseup event, I'm checking if both the containers overlap. But when I'm calling `stage.getObjectsUnderPoint`, Its returning array of `[Shape, Image, Shape, Image]`. What I was expecting is both of the containers.

I may be missing to set some other properties of stage or something else.

Tried to find over web, no luck.

```
   var canvas = null;
    var stage = null;
    var update = false;

    function tick(){
          if(update){
                stage.update();
                update = false;
          }
    }

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
          createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
          createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
          stage.enableMouseOver(36);

          var getContainer = function(cname, x, y, imageName){

                var container= new createjs.Container();
                container.mouseEnabled = true;
                container.onPress= function(event){
                      var target= event.target;

                      stage.addChild(target);

                      var offset = {
                            x: target.x - stage.mouseX,
                            y: target.y - stage.mouseY
                      };

                      event.onMouseMove = function (ev) {
                            target.x = ev.stageX + offset.x;
                            target.y = ev.stageY + offset.y;
                            update = true;
                      }

                      event.onMouseUp = function(ev){
                            var objects = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(ev.stageX, ev.stageY);
                            event.stageX, event.stageY
                            objects.forEach(function(object){
                                  console.log('name: ' + object.name);
                            });
                      }
                };

                container.name = cname;

                var shape = new createjs.Shape();
                shape.graphics
                      .setStrokeStyle(10)
                      .beginFill('#f0f0f0')
                      .beginStroke("#000")
                      .drawCircle(x, y, 100);
                shape.name = cname + ' - shape';

                container.addChild(shape);

                var image = new Image();
                image.onload = function(event){
                      var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
                      bitmap.regX = image.width/2;
                      bitmap.regY = image.height/2;
                      bitmap.x = x, bitmap.y = y;
                      bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = 0.8;

                      bitmap.name = cname + ' - image';

                      container.addChild(bitmap);
                      update = true;
                };
                image.src = imageName;

                return container;

          };

          var container= getContainer("Original Container", 200, 300, 'cat1.png');

          var diffContainer = getContainer("Different Container", 600, 300, 'cat2.png');

          stage.addChild(container);
          stage.addChild(diffContainer);

          update = true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend posting CreateJS issues in the community forum
http://community.createjs.com

Your sample is working as expected. You are checking which objects are under the mouse at the point where you release it. getObjectsUnderPoint will just tell you which objects will fill pixels at a single x/y coordinate.

If you want to determine if the entire containers overlap, you will need to do more than that, such as checking bounding boxes (or something more complex to do circle->box collision).

Cheers.